# Build customer ratings from subscription datetime data for a recommendation system

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, matrix, recommender-system, rating

I want to build a recommendation system with only some customer's subscription and unsubscription date. I have a database that looks like:

```
Id  Prod_Id     Prod_Grp_Id        Min     Max
 1       P3              G2     201701  201712
 4       P2              G2     201709  201811
 3       P3              G2     201704  201810
 1       P1              G1     201707  201811
 5       P2              G1     201706  201811
```

where `Id` is the customer's **id**, `Prod_id` the **id** of the product we are selling, `Prod_Grp_Id` the group of products that `Prod_Id` belongs to. And the two last variables are datetime in format `%YYYYMM%` where `Min` stands for the subscription's month of one customer for the considered product and `Max` is the month of unsubscription.

To build the recommendation system, I need to go from this database to the matrix of ratings based on the given dates of subscrption and unsubscription.

The only clue I have in mind is that if the elapsed time of subscription for a client is low, that should mean he didn't like the produit, so I'm expecting a bad rating of this customer for the product.

So, what is the best way to build strong estimators of customer's ratings in this specific case ?

Thanks also for any advice !

Comment: As you've observed, a pretty standard way to do this is use the days from subscription to unsubscription as the individual rating of each product, then run them through whatever recommendation model you choose, so would just start with that and change approach if the recommendations look terrible.

Comment: Thank you @Philip for your comment. But I'm conviced it should be a little bit more complex than that. For example I have customers who discovered new products recently and liked it, since it's a new product, the elapsed time between now and their subscription will be very low according to this method. So it fails there to get an accurate rating for these customers. See ?
I'm looking for any documentation or paper about this marketing issue but can't still find anything. Do you have any references to recommend ?
Thanks...